# The remote SSH server is configured to allow weak encryption algorithms

Tags: linux, ssh

```
The following weak client-to-server encryption algorithms are supported by the remote service:

aes256-cbc


The following weak server-to-client encryption algorithms are supported by the remote service:

aes256-cbc
```

Я использую инструмент для сканирования уязвимостей - openvas. Для ssh выдаёт такое предупреждение.
Вопрос, как это пофиксить и чтобы остался доступ по ssh?

Comment: обновить ssh сервер. ну ключики, скорее всего уже не подойдут, поэтому заново ssh-copy-id. логин-пароль, конечно, останутся прежними

Comment: > apt-get update это делал

Comment: это только обновляет информацию о пакетах, а обновление идет через `apt-get upgrade`. в новых версиях, кажется, уже можно одной командой через apt, но это не точно. вообще на админских форумах вы бы сразу получили `man apt`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333728/110559